# mysqli_real_escape_string working using post but not working on if inserting value by assigning value to another variable

Tags: php

There are a lot of questions regarding mysqli_real_escape_string. but still didn't able to find issue.

```
 $username=$_POST['name'];
  $comment=$_POST['comment'];
   if($comment=="" || $username=="") {
    echo "All fields Required"
   }
   else { 
    $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$username);
    $Comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$comment);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $sql="INSERT INTO comment (,user_name,comment,comment_date)
    VALUES('$username','$comment','$date')";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    if($result) {
      echo "comment posted successfully"
    }
```

if am using this to insert comment in database. but mysqli_real_escape_string() is not escaping any invalid char but its working fine by directly inserting post[] variable

```
$comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['comment']);
```

this is working fine.

Comment: `$Comment` and `$comment` are **totally different** variables

Comment: Incorrect comma, it should be `$sql="INSERT INTO comment (user_name, ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this does not work?

```
$Comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$comment);
```

and this does?

```
$comment=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['comment']);
```

On the first one, you write `$Comment` with a captical C, on the second with a lower case "c" (which you are using later on). Change the varibale to `$comment`and it should work. Php is case sensitive.